# rsync: rename File exists (17) on Fedora from a mounted Drobo CIFS share

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I'm running a daily `cronjob`, using `rsync` to copy files from a Drobo FS, which is mounted locally via `autofs` on demand as a CIFS share. Why do I get these warnings about the file existing and a rename? Could a file be in use at the time of backup? Are there any other `rsync` options I can include?

```
/usr/bin/nice -n +20 /usr/bin/rsync --update -raz --progress --no-specials
--no-devices --fuzzy --delay-updates --delete-delay --exclude cache/
--exclude=.cache --exclude /local/dsm/sbin/exclude.txt /mnt/Public/myuser/
myuser@mydomain:/mnt/myfolder

RESULT CODE: 12

ERROR OUTPUT:
rsync: rename "/mnt/myfolder/myuser/Book Analysis
Project/loading_utils/.data_loader.py.MPk9YW" -> "myuser/Book Analysis
Project/loading_utils/.~tmp~/data_loader.py": File exists (17)
```

Edit: the `--fuzzy` option came from [this other SE thread](https://serverfault.com/a/489293/359447).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the errors to disappear. [This user](https://serverfault.com/a/594277/359447) mentions using the `-b` option with the -`-backup-dir=DIR`, so all files that are different will go into `DIR`.  I have not been using the `-b` option but I noticed what currently happens. The original file is placed in a newly created directory, in this case `.~tmp~`:
ls -al myuser/Book\ Analysis\ Project/scripts/.~tmp~/
total 37
drwx------ 2 myuser domain users  1400 Jul 14 07:28 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 myuser domain users  3640 Jul  8 12:09 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser domain users 14385 Jul  5 14:42 book_data_extractor.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser domain users  6038 Jul  5 14:42 cfg_extractor.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser domain users 10963 Jul  8 19:44 run_book_data_extractor.py

I found another [suggestion here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/rsync-cannot-delete-non-empty-directory-4175597350/#post5655222), which is to use `--delete-excluded`, which as this user points out:

> If you have excluded files or directories from being transferred,
> `--delete-excluded` will remove them from the destination side (this does not have to be the "remote server", you can use `rsync` to copy
> from a server to the local computer) if it finds them there. For
> instance, if you use `--exclude=*.o --delete-excluded`, then if `rsync`
> finds any files ending in .o on the destination side, it will remove
> them whether they exist in the source directory or not.

Once the rsync ran and deleted all of the `.~tmp~` files/directories, the errors ceased.

However the `-b` option appears to create another sub-folder if the file changes multiple times. Outside of changing to `rsnapshot` I take it this is the correct action? It ends up looking like this:

```
/myuser/original-file/original-file/original-file/original-file/original-file
```

The full option looks like this: `--backup-dir=/path/to/original-file`